# Creating playing table background with greenish rays coming from the middle

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Could anybody please advise steps in Adobe Illustrator for creating a greenish background with "rays" emitting from its middle?

[image]

1. I.e. which tool to use for creating the rays?
2. How to create the "inner" shadow on the rectangular border?
3. Which tool to create the lighter spot in the middle

I wonder how to approach this in Adobe Illustrator, because I need a vector output - an .fxg file for my Flash game. I. e. I can not use Photoshop or Gimp here.

Thank you for any hints/directions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample image was most likely created in Photoshop. Photoshop makes the inset rectangle a bit easier, but the rays more difficult to make. Either application will work though.

### Rays

- Draw one ray, a triangle. Wide at top, point at the bottom.
- With the triangle selected choose Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform
  [image: rays]
- Once you have the rays, you can either choose Object > Expand Appearance and then delete the rays you do not want. Or you can create a clipping mask to simply hide the rays you do not want.
- Fill the rays with a gradient of your choice.

### Background

- The background is merely a gradient filled rectangle.

### Inner shadow around edge

- Select all, Group (object > Group), and then choose Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow and adjust the setting.

### Lighter part in the middle.

This is simply a rounded rectangle with reduced opacity. There is a slight bevel effect on it. This is easily done in Photoshop but takes quite a few more steps in Illustrator. Essentially you want a dark stroke at the top inside edge of the shape and a light stroke on the bottom inside edge of the shape.

### Inset Rectangle

- Use the Rounded rectangle tool to draw the rectangle. Or simply draw a standard rectangle ad use Effect > Stylize > Round Corners to round the corners dynamically.
- Fill with a simply dark to light, top to bottom gradient
- Choose Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow and adjust the settings to your liking.
  [image: glow]

I didn't address color anywhere. The colors are all merely gradients. There's nothing special about how the color is applied to anything in that image.