# How to create "rays" around an object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to creat rays around an object. I've tried to do it but I'm not quite satisfied with the result...

[image]

Any idea how to make in a more systematic way?

Comment: I probably should have asked for clarification before posting an answer, but could you clarify why you're not satisfied with that result? Is it the placement of the rays or the overall aesthetic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw a circle....

Then using the **Stroke Panel** configure a **dashed stroke**:

[image]

- The Stroke Weight controls how long the "rays" are.
- The dash field controls how thick the "rays" are.
- the gap field controls the space between the "rays".

When you're happy with things...

- choose `Object > Expand Appearance`
- then choose `Object > Expand`
- click `OK` for the dialog.
- Then use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to select and delete anything you do *not* want.

There are **several** questions here with other techniques:

[Ray effect in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17826/ray-effect-in-illustrator)

[Creating playing table background with greenish rays coming from the middle](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16355/creating-playing-table-background-with-greenish-rays-coming-from-the-middle)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this would qualify as a "systematic" solution but I think you can give off more of a glimmering appearing by simply turning your rays into triangles instead of rectangles.

[image: gem artwork]

You could also experiment with alternating rays of varying length

[image: gem artwork]

Answer (score 0):

1.Put a circle behind your diamond to make sure that the rays are equally far from the diamond.
[image]

2.Make your rays with pen tool and rotate them like in image.
[image]

3. Delete the layer with circle.